# Why does there exist a continuous map with no fixed point $f\colon S^n\to S^n$ when $n\ge 1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spheres

> Why does there exist a continuous map with no fixed point $f\colon S^n\to S^n$ when $n\ge 1$?

I can find a continuous map that has no fixed points for the case $n=1$ but I fail to see how this generalizes.

Answer (score 17):

Take $f$ to be the antipodal map.

Comment: does the map $f(x)=-x$ work? also can you explain why there are no fixed points if $f$ is antipodal map?

Comment: That's exactly the antipodal map. It can't have fixed point because the only point such that $x=-x$ is $0$, which does not belong to any $S^n$.